# Are there useful utilities for visualizing rosgraphs?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

--Just in case there are others, and for those who may have missed some of the tools that *do* exist--

---

Are there any useful tools to help visualize a ROS computation graph?
(Or to generate nice pictures for papers based on these graphs?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44954/are-there-useful-utilities-for-visualizing-rosgraphs?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen that people use [rxgraph](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxgraph), but often don't realize they can also use [xdot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/xdot) to generate images from a saved .dot file.

```
roslaunch somepkg somefilename.launch
rxgraph -o somefilename.dot
rosrun xdot xdot.py somefilename.dot
```

(And you can [edit](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) somefilename.dot in realtime which I think is a useful way to generate figures that fit the needs of a paper or a presentation.)

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1